# Relative frequency histogram in R

Tags: r

I need a histogram using the relative frequency. This is the code that I'm using. I'd like to have 7 bars instead of 10. How could I change that?

```
histo<-hist(DatosTA1$Datos)
barplot(histo$counts/50,col="green",space=0)->bp   # n=length(variable)
axis(1,at=b,labels=b)
title(ylab="Frecuencia relativa",xlab="Distribución de frecuencias 
                del tiempo relativo")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi.  You haven't provided enough information to properly answer this question.  If you data is not a factor type, look at  setting the argument:  nint 
An integer specifying the number of histogram bins, applicable only when breaks is unspecified or NULL in the call. Ignored when the variable being plotted is a factor.

Comment: @viviana selenia use hist() and set breaks argument equal to 7